# Does any finite group of order $2m$ with odd $m$ have a subgroup of index 2?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $2m$ where $m>1$ is an *odd* natural number.

> **Question.** Is it true that any such $G$  has a subgroup $H$ of index 2?

If yes, I would be grateful for a reference or a proof.

Comment: This is a classical one. See for instance [this MathSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/225987/35400) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/488053/35400). I guess it also appeared on MO many times. For instance, in [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/163705/14094), it is explained that the same signature argument shows that if the 2-Sylow of $G$ are cyclic and nontrivial then $G$ has a subgroup of index 2.

Comment: @YCor: Thank you! I never know which question is suitable for MO and which for MSE. Feel free to vote to migrate to MSE or to close as duplicate.

Comment: This is Exercise 4.2.13 of 'Abstract Algebra, 3rd ed.'  by David S. Dummit and Richard M. Foote. Many solutions for exercises in this text are online. For this exercise, see https://linearalgebras.com/solution-abstract-algebra-exercise-4-2-13.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in fact in algebra classes in Germany, this is a well-known example or homework problem: Consider the regular action of $G$. Then an element of order $2$ in $G$ is a product of $m$ transpositions, so it is an odd permutation. Thus $G\cap\text{Alt}_{2m}$ is a subgroup of index $2$.

This generalization follows from [Burnside's normal p-complement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_p-complement): Let $p$ be the smallest prime divisor of $\lvert G\rvert$, and suppose that the Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ is cyclic. Then $G$ has a normal subgroup of index $\lvert P\rvert$.

Comment: Many-many thanks! I took the liberty to add details to your answer (for the other users of MO). Roll back if you don't like my editing.